# Automated posting to Facebook and Twitter from Joomla blog?

Tags: joomla-3.5

For a Joomla blog, we want to be able to create the blog Joomla articles and schedule them with a start publication date when they appear on the website. We also want them to automatically be posted to the company's Facebook Fan Page, and Twitter account.

Is there a Joomla extension that would accomplish this and recognize the posting would coincide with the start publication date of the Joomla Article?

I assume something in the CRON needs to be scheduled to do this? If so, is this a simple shell/PHP script to look at the MySQL database for this Joomla installation and handle the auto posting through an API for Facebook and Twitter? Or is this re-inventing the wheel and there is already a Joomla extension solution for this?

Comment: Have you had a look at jed: http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/social-auto-publish

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-share/autotweet-ng-pro, is from our JSE member http://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/174/anibal, give it a try, all their extensions: http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/profile/details/164804

Answer (score 3):

AutoTweetNG does this, see http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/autotweet-ng

You can set AutoTweetNG to push social feed content to Facebook, Twitter and LinekdIn.  When an item is published, either on a schedule or on creation, it is pushed out to the social channels you set up in the component.  There is a free version that is limited to 2 channels, or a pro version that can post to as many channels as you like.  It does not require a cron to operate.

Free version: http://www.extly.com/autotweet-ng-free.html

Pro version: http://www.extly.com/autotweet-ng-pro.html

I've been using it for a couple of years, and it has always worked well.

Answer (score 0):

This extension has scheduler, I haven't tested it.

https://foobla.com/joomla/obsocialsubmit

Answer (score 0):

I have used both extensions and are working fine. 
I just want to point out that the 
https://foobla.com/joomla/obsocialsubmit
is simpler for a front end developer with medium Joomla knowledge  and the support was very fast and accurate.
Good luck.